# How to create VLAN in ZTE ZXHN H298A Router

Tags: router, vlan, modem

I have a router / modem called ZTE ZXHN H298A V1.0 TTN.19T4_210317.

I'm sharing my network with neighbours but I want to capsule my network and/or the guests network to protect my local network. So I tried to create a VLAN for the guest's WiFi but I get an error message "Current operation is invalid, please check configuration parameters.".

See my try in the screenshot:
[VLAN Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Li4v.png)

How can I isolate my network (all LANs and SSID1 and SSID5) from the guest's network (SSID2 and SSID6) correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I don't want that my devices and the neighbour's devices talk to each other.

Comment: That router doesn't support VLANs. The LAN ports aren't separable either, so you'll need another router.

Comment: Oh okay. But what is this LAN Group for where I can select different LANs and SSIDs?